# Getting Data from firebase in ascending or descending order from collection using feild

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am working with firebase. I want to get data from a collection in ascending order according to a feild inside the collection.

I have a `LeaderBoard` collection.
inside that i have `player` that contains 2 feild.
`Time` and `name`.

In `firebase database` it show option to achive this using

```
.collection("LeaderBoard")
.orderBy("Time", "asc")
```

But I don't understand what we have to use before `.collection` to get data.

How can I get data in ascending order from a collection in `firebase datastore` using a feild?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the answer to this and I found the solution on how one can achieve this.

```
        const q = query(name, orderBy("Time"))
        onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
            let data = [];
            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                data.push({ ...doc.data(), found: false });
            })
        })
```

This data will contain your data in ascending order.

Here `name` is
`const LeaderBoard = collection(db, "LeaderBoard");`